# I can't solve pre-processing of OCR

Tags: numbers, ocr, digits

I'm using Cenparmi digit databases. (6,000 digits pictures)
I already tried to make sequences 
[ pre-processing > noise filter > thinning > normalization > backpropagation]
But, recognition error rate was very high (60~70% )
I shocked , why!?! and found the reason
I guess it was the pre-processing problem
[picture-1](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B-aP4irzIlNPcnNiTTRNYV9WYms&authuser=0)

for example, this picture looks like no. 8 or no. 0
but actually this is no. 0, then I need to organize this,
I used my algorithm, first checked 3x3 area
(If have hole, then delete) I used this processing, 2 times
but I got another problems...
For example....Real no.8 digit became no. 0(not all)
and when thinning processing, changed to monster digits...
For example...

[this is no.1](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B-aP4irzIlNPcnNiTTRNYV9WYms&authuser=0)

If have small hole or noise
then pixels became grow or disappear
Now, I'm confusing... I don't know what I have to do...
I'm making the this project alone for 6 months and stop...
I tried to find many thesis, 
but I didn't find detail thesis that how to learn pre-processing about handwritten digits
help me and teach me solution please!